# Distance between sequential points postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgis

My table is as follows

```
1;"2015-10-02";"POINT(lat,lon) as geometry"
2;"2015-10-03";"POINT(lat,lon) as geometry"
3;"2015-10-04";"POINT(lat,lon) as geometry"
```

How can I find the distance between two sequential points?

So I'd have id=1 and id=2 distance between them = 99m (distances would be found between [1,2],[2,3],[3,4] and so on

then if distance < 100m aggregate them

I have not go very far with it

This gives me the distance but I don't know how to get the next row's geometry

```
SELECT st_distance_sphere(t.latlon,next.latlon) from test as t where id=1
```

Then I tried to read the distance as a additional column but could figure out a correct query

```
UPDATE test SET dist=ST_Distance(test.latlon, next.geom) 
FROM (SELECT latlon FROM test WHERE id = test.id + 1) into b;

1;"2015-10-02";"POINT(lat,lon) as geometry";distance between 1 and 2
2;"2015-10-03";"POINT(lat,lon) as geometry";distance between 2 and 3
3;"2015-10-04";"POINT(lat,lon) as geometry";distance between 3 and 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To take the distance between current point and next point you can use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) `lead` like this:

```
select
        test.*,
        st_distance(latlon, lead(latlon, 1, latlon) over(order by id)) as distance
    from test;
```